# Microsoft MS Project XX.X Object Library Reference Missing from References List in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-project

Ultimately I want to build a MS Project file using early binding from VBA behind XLS or MPP.

In order to do that, it is my understanding that you should go to **Tools**--> **References** and select the **Microsoft Project XX.X Object Library**.

Unfortunately, it wasn't in the list.

The References pop-up allows you  to **browse**, and select the reference library manually.  Great!  But, where do I look, and what file do I select to import this reference?

Comment: Is MS Project installed? And if so which version? • Look into your program folder eg `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16` and look for `MSPRJ.OLB`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are looking in Excel VBA References's list, it should just show up. Here's mine:

[image: references available in excel]

Note that I see it as `Microsoft Office Project XX.X Object Library`, you asked about `Microsoft Project XX.X Object Library` (lacking `Office`).

My environment is Win10; both Excel 2016 32-bit and Project 2016 32-bit are installed.

Perhaps try re-installing your Office components? Perhaps try making sure you have both the same bit architecture (32 or 64).